# Only status updates on the feed in Facebook

Tags: facebook, status

Is there a way to only see status updates on the Facebook feed? There was a feature in the previous versions of Facebook, but I think they have taken it out. Is there any workaround? Or any app that does that?

Comment: Seems like it should be possible with a Greasemonkey script. I'll do a search...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have yet to try it, but after a Google search I came up with this link: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/79506

It's set to show only status messages, videos, photos, links and events but, apparently, he'll be adding an option to let the user choose which to see when.

If you want to only see status updates, all the time, just leave this

```
/* Status */
allowedmsgs[11] = 1;
```

as is and set all the other flags to "0" instead of "1".

If you're on Chrome you can follow the instructions at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/ or do a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&q=%22greasemonkey+for+chrome%22).

```
https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&q="greasemonkey+for+chrome"
```

It seems like Chrome natively works with Greasemonkey scripts, by the way, so you should have nothing additional to install. Just click "install" after downloading the script.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it in Chrome?

Comment: I edited and tried the script in chrome, facebook refreshes continuously and the script is not working, but I think I will search more and will update the post here if I find something interesting. Thanks for the information Alex.